# Why I have to click twice to show Div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that I should show a message in front of it so i'm using the following jq code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $("#msg").html(data);

 var pos = $("#answer2ticker").offset();
 $("#msg").offset({top: pos.top, left: pos.left});

 $("#msg").show();
 </script>

 <div class="alert alert-danger" id="msg" style="position: absolute;" hidden="hidden" onclick="$(this).hide();"> </div>
```

THE PROBLEM:
the message shows the first time normally, but when I hide it and try to show it again, I have to click on show twice.

so hiding is normal, but showing has to be called twice.

Comment: Where's the button here?

Comment: #answer2ticker is the button, and I need to show the message next to it, so i'm using its position

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that your `onclick` attribute is breaking it. Try the unobtrusive way by placing it in your JavaScript.

Comment: Waw, it is correct that the onclick the problem, but why is this possible, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use jQuery toggle function?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var data = "test";
 $("#msg").html(data);

    $("#answer2ticker").click(function() {
        $('#msg').toggle();
    });  
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/LbEVL/1/